# Semantically correct way to add titles and subtitles for non-sectioning elements (HTML)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-heading

What html elements are most appropriate to add titles and subtitles to components which are not related to explicit or implicit website sections, e.g. table or figure captions, cards etc.?

According to W3, headings are not recommended for subtitles:

> h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection.

But it also seems that heading tags are not to be used outside of section context:

> Heading content defines the header of a section (whether explicitly marked up using sectioning content elements, or implied by the heading content itself).

Does this mean that usage of `<h4>` in the example below is not correct and `<div>`'s must be used instead?

```
 <figcaption>
     <h4>Title</h4>
     <div class="byline">Byline</div>
     <p>Some description.</p>
 </figcaption>
```

Comment: It depends on the wider context. Ignoring the figure and figcaption elements, does the h4 element make sense relative to the headings that precede it? Does the text of the h4 heading and that which follows represent a subsection of the section created by the h3 element that precedes it?. If so, then it's fine. Otherwise, its best to avoid using it.

Comment: So does this mean that it is fine to use h4 as card UI element titles/captions because each card represent logical subsection of some larger container (e.g. `<main>` section)?

Comment: Not `<main>`. `<main>` is not a sectioning element. The larger container in that case would be `<body>`. And `<h4>` would only be appropriate if the containing section was headed by an `<h3>`. Which in turn should be in a section headed by an `<h2>`, etc

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER: The use of `h4` inside `figcaption` is *not* structurally or semantically correct.

In my original answer I said:

> Good question. You've missed one thing though, evident from the title
> of your question, which refers to 'non-sectioning elements'. The
> [`figure`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)
> element *is* a [sectioning
> root](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#sectioning-root)
> element. These are interesting elements, in that they are considered
> 'part of the surrounding flow' (to quote [the
> spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element:the-figure-element-6)),
> but 'the sections and headings inside these elements do not contribute
> to the outlines of their ancestors'.

What I should have added, is that this [document outline algorithm was never implemented](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html) by any browser. So while *in theory* it was true that you could use a heading inside a [`figcaption`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element) without forming part of the document outline, in practice it wasn't so.

Since I wrote the answer back in April 2021, WHATWG seems to have finally faced reality, removing all references to 'sectioning roots' and the like. Where [the spec used to say](https://web.archive.org/web/20211231200635/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#outlines):

> The outline for a sectioning content element or a sectioning root
> element consists of a list of one or more potentially nested sections.

[It now just says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#headings-and-outlines-2):

> The outline is all headings in a document, in tree order.

On the question of how to markup subheadings, the recommended use of the `hgroup` element has also changed, and the links I provided in my original answer are now out of date. See [my recently updated answer to *HTML subheading markup in 2020*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66828087/2652785) for more details on this.