# HTML subheading markup in 2020

Tags: html

I'm trying to clarify how subheadings should be markuped in HTML in 2020.

The *HTML Living Standard*, 1 September 2020 spec says to use a [`<hgroup>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element):

> The element is used to group a set of h1–h6 elements when the heading has multiple levels, such as subheadings, alternative titles, or taglines.

The *[Headings and sections](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#outlines)* section of the same spec explains how the HTML outline algorithm generates a content outline showing that the subheading in a `<h2>` in the following example the does not appear in/disrupt a page's structural outline.

```html
<hgroup id="document-title">
  <h1>HTML</h1>
  <h2>Living Standard — Last Updated 12 August 2016</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Splendid! Except the usage notes for [`<hgroup>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup) (Last modified on 12 Apr 2020 at the time of writing) says:

> [Given that] the HTML outline algorithm is not implemented in any browsers—then the  semantics are in practice only theoretical.

But marking things up semantically has practical application with respect to accessibility, so what to do?

Sifting through mostly quite outdated search results, the best guides I can find seem to point towards using a `<p>` (eg. *[Usability & Web Accessibility](https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/headings)*). However, w3.org's *Common idioms without dedicated elements* page that is typically used as a reference for this technique redirects to whatwg.org's version (following [the MOU between the two orgs](https://www.w3.org/2019/04/WHATWG-W3C-MOU.html) in May 2019) which doesn't include the `<p>` for subheadings idiom because, of course, there is the `<hgroup>` element.

And so I've come full circle to my original question; how should I markup a subheading in HTML in 2020?

Comment: It's somewhat chicken and egg. If no browser supports it, why should you implement it? If nobody implements it, why should browsers support it? — There is a specification for what you want to do, so you should use that, especially if it doesn't have any drawbacks. The more people stick to the spec, the more useful it becomes.

Comment: That W3C page, *Common idioms without dedicated elements*, appears to have moved here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html. So much for [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)! ;-)

Comment: Thank @Kal, for supplying the ref for that and bonus points for the URI link. :D The *next* curiosity in this trail is trying to fathom the chain of supersession. Following the version links given in [the intro to HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/) as best as I can understand the 28 Jan 2021 version is superseded by itself… :S

Comment: Hmm… 'This version' is the same as 'Latest published version' (just with a different URL), so that's good do know. It's dated 14 Dec 2017, the same as the 'Previous Version', but it also supersedes that version on 28 Jan 21. And apparently it's completely different to 'Latest published version *of HTML*', which redirects you to the WHATWG spec. I don't know what you're talking about, it's all as clear as mud! ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: Since I posted this answer, WHATWG seems to have finally faced reality, removing references to *outline algorithms*, *sectioning roots* and the like.

In the updated specs, `hgroup` is still with us, but they have changed their recommendations on how to use it. Where [they used to say](https://web.archive.org/web/20211231200635/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element):

> Other h1–h6 elements of heading content in the hgroup element indicate
> subheadings or subtitles or (secondary) alternative titles.

[The current advice](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element) is now:

> The element may be used to group an h1–h6 element with one or more p
> elements containing content representing a subheading, alternative
> title, or tagline.

So the essence of my original answer was correct—you shouldn't use so-called sectioning elements to repurpose heading tags. Whether you place your `p` subheading inside a `hgroup` is really a matter of personal preference. :-)

---

My original answer:

If the underlying structure (outline) of your document is important to you, don't rely on [sectioning elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines) to create an outline (despite what you read in many articles), and certainly don't rely on the `hgroup` element, which [W3C deprecated](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html). The W3C is quite clear on [what *not* to do](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-html52-20170228/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines):

> h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles,
> alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for
> a new section or subsection.

The spec is less helpful in telling us what we *should* do. The WHATWG just sort of pretends that `hgroup` (and the document outline algorithm) is properly supported by browsers, [declaring](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/sections.html#the-hgroup-element):

> The point of using hgroup in these examples is to prevent the h2
> element (which acts as a secondary title) from creating a separate
> section of its own in any outline and to instead cause the contents of
> the h2 to be shown in rendered output from the outline algorithm in
> some way to indicate that it is not the title of a separate section
> but instead just a secondary title in a group of titles.

The W3C is a little more pragmatic, acknowledging that:

> HTML does not have a dedicated mechanism for marking up subheadings,
> alternative titles or taglines.

They also suggest some possible workarounds here: [Common idioms without dedicated elements: Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-html52-20170228/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines).

With all those semantic elements in HTML5, you'd think they could have just given us a `<subhead>` tag or something. ([They did actually toy with the idea back in 2013.](https://rawgit.com/w3c/subline/master/index.html)) In lieu of this, a `<span>` or `p` with `class="subhead"` works for me.

If you don't care about outlines (or accessibility), you can use sectioning elements to create the *appearance* of structure if you want to (since browser's will try and make the headings *look* right), and you can use `hgroup` with your own CSS styling.

Further reading: [There Is No Document Outline Algorithm](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html).

Comment: WHATWG doesn't just “pretend” that `hgroup` is supported... it actually *is:* https://caniuse.com/?search=hgroup (probably because WHATWG is steered by the companies that actually make the browsers). Although I personally wish they hadn't gone that way.

Comment: @pbarney, if you read my full answer, you will see that I wrote 'If you don't care about outlines … you can use `hgroup` with your own CSS styling'. But the whole point of `hgroup` (and I'll quote again from WHATWG) was to 'prevent the h2 element (which acts as a secondary title) from creating a separate section of its own in any outline', and it does NOT do this. So no, it is not properly supported—from an accessibility perspective, it may as well just be a meaningless `div`. caniuse.com is a great resource (I use it all the time) but it does not tell you the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much I'd worry about MDN's warning that

> the HTML outline algorithm is not implemented in any browsers—then the semantics are in practice only theoretical.

If the semantics are only theoretical, then using `<hgroup>` won't have any effect one way or the other. So two choices. The WHATWG method:

```
<hgroup>
  <h1>HTML</h1>
  <h2>Living Standard</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Or the W3C way:

```
<header>
  <h1>HTML</h1>
  <p class="subhead">Living Standard</p>
</header>
```

If MDN is right, and "the semantics are only theoretical", and they are right that `<hgroup>` "is unlikely to go away", then these two methods will both work. So choose whichever one you prefer.

Comment: A useful answer, which shows both the 'WHATWG method' and the 'W3C way', but I'd disagree with your statement, 'using <hgroup> won't have any effect one way or the other'. It does have an effect, since the `h2` subheading will form part of the implicit document outline, just like any other `h2` on the page. That's not the intention here, so the warning is worth noting.

Comment: You left out the conditional. What I said was, "*if* MDN is right, and 'the semantics are only theoretical'" then there won't be any outline. That's the crux of my point.

Comment: MDN *is* right, and what they mean is that the `h2` will, in practice, behave as if there was no `hgroup`. That doesn't mean 'there won't be any outline'—quite the opposite. It means `h2` will form part of the implicit document outline, which is almost certainly not what you want when you chose `hgroup`!

Answer (score 1):

this tag not supported in html5 so is better you don't use it!

> The [`<hgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup) element has been removed from the HTML5 (W3C)
> specification, but it still is in the WHATWG version of HTML. It is
> partially implemented in most browsers, though, so is unlikely to go
> away. However, given that a key purpose of the `<hgroup>` element is to
> affect how headings are displayed by the outline algorithm defined in
> the HTML specification—but the HTML outline algorithm is not
> implemented in any browsers—then the `<hgroup>` semantics are in
> practice only theoretical. So the HTML5 (W3C) specification provides
> advice on how to mark up [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles
> and taglines without using](http://web.archive.org/web/20210420223634/https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html) `<hgroup>`.

Comment: Regardless of W3C's suggestion, `<hgroup>` is [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=hgroup) by every major browser. Even so, it's semantically troublesome and should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Standard [§ 4.3.7 The hgroup element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element):

> The hgroup element represents a heading and related content. The
> element may be used to group an h1–h6 element with one or more p
> elements containing **content representing a subheading**, alternative
> title, or tagline.

Two examples of using paragraph elements for sub heading text are provided:

```
<hgroup>
 <h1>The reality dysfunction</h1>
 <p>Space is not the only void</p>
</hgroup>

<hgroup>
 <h1>Dr. Strangelove</h1>
 <p>Or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</p>
</hgroup>
```